# Do you get points for editing somebody else's post?

Tags: discussion, edits, edit-badges, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Do you get points for editing somebody else's post? I see a few users who constantly go around just editing others posts. Are they doing this because they are rewarded with points? Do you get points for editing your own posts?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you don't have editing privileges for what you're editing then your edit creates a suggested edit. If that gets approved, you will get 2 reputation.

For normal edits when you have the edit privileges already there is no reputation given, but there are badges to be earned.

Comment: Ah! So that's why there's almost instant, futile, edits on pretty much anything posted. Badge hunters I gather.

Comment: I feel there should be mechanism for upvoting edit...? :p An edit may add a lot than an original answer had to offer, but simply not put as separate answer just because it would have been redundant...If say edit is more than 80% of original answer then the OP doing edit deserves at least 2 points for further upvotes on that answer... (am not badge hunter...barely done any edit in past...but about to do my possibly first edit  xD)

Comment: The big issue is when you have a totally wrong answer -> you put the right answer -> the first user (or someone else) edit the wrong answer using your solution -> people start to down-vote for you since it was posted after the one that was wrong! I had this exact case several days ago (history of the answer show the first wrong answer but seems like the user tried to hide it and removed his comments from the discussion).

Answer (score 5):

You get 2 rep for an accepted edit suggestion.  Beyond that, no.